# Zero inflated dependent variable and tree ml regression models

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, zero-inflation, overdispersion, bagging

I wonder, if tree based ml models (e.g. xgb or random forests) are actually susceptible to zero inflated dependent variables (DVs) in the case of regression (in a sense the DV is at least bi-modal)? IMHO one could just use them as is. Some people train the trees on data where the DVs > 0 and use a model that predicts whether the DVs are 0 or greater (e.g. multiplying the unadjusted values with a probability - see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/zero-inflated-regression-c7dfc656d8af)).

Comment: What do you mean by "susceptible to"?

Comment: I don't see any issues with using a zero-inflated DV. Tree-based models are used all the time for anomaly detection problems and with the right features, usually provide great results. Triaging the problem to is it 0/other and then predicting the other category class may work, but can also overcomplicate the solution, especially if you want to deploy and maintain your models.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding - I refer to regression will try to make more explicit

Comment: @jbowman as in bad predictive performance. In a sense the model could come up with an average for the bi-modal DV rather than first split the feature space into bins representing the bimodality (ignoring all the other IVs)